# How do I create a shortcut with the name set to [PRODUCTNAME] in a VS Setup and Deployment project?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, shortcut, setup-deployment

In my VS Setup & Deployment project, I want to create a desktop shortcut whose name is set to the [ProductName] property. Instead of using the property, the setup program simply treats [ProductName] as a string literal. How can I get it to behave the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using some hard coded name and use build events to rename the shortcut upon installation?

Comment: I realize I could probably do something with a custom action, but I'm trying to find the simplest method here. Also, I'd need some more explanation of what you mean for me to accept this as an answer.

Comment: No problem, but tell me, what do you really trying to accomplish?  Is there some deeper reason for you not wanting to type ProductName in two places?

Comment: This is part of an automated build process; I only want to change the ProductName in one place and have it propogate everywhere it's referenced within the install, including the name of the shortcut.

Comment: OK, but how often does the productName change?  What you want is unsupported.